# How can I adjust this 3 Table MySQL join query to eliminate rows that contain a null value column?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, multiple-tables

I'm not quite sure how to best word this question. I don't necessarily need a way to eliminate rows that contain a column possessing a null value -- I just need to figure out how to adjust my query so it's only generating the single row result for each user that I need... Here's some background info to help clarify:

Alright, so I have 5 tables: users, local_ads (local ads), local_rev (local revenue report), nat_ads (national ads), and nat_rev (national revenue report).

Every month, a user submits a National Revenue Report and a Local Revenue Report. When the user creates their monthly reports, they are given a unique report ID for both local and national reports. The report_id and the corresponding user_id is stored in the their respective tables (local_rev or nat_rev).

The user then submits Ads to each report. The local Ads submitted for the month's Local Report are stored in the local_ads table, and for a given user, each of their Ads share the same report_id. The same is true for National Ads.

Every Ad in both the local_rev and nat_rev tables have a column for price and size.

I am trying to execute a query that will generate the Local Ad total size, Local Ad quantity, Local Ad total price, National Ad total size, National Ad quantity, and National Ad total price for each user WHERE month="x."

Here is the query that has come the closest to what I need:

```
SELECT u.franchise, lr.lrr_id, CountLocId, TotalPrice, nr.nrr_id, CountNatId, TotalNMoney,     
(
TotalPrice + TotalNMoney
)TotalRev
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN local_rev lr ON u.user_id = lr.user_id
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT lrr_id, COUNT( lad_id ) CountLocId, SUM( price ) TotalPrice
FROM local_ads
GROUP BY lrr_id
)la ON lr.lrr_id = la.lrr_id
LEFT JOIN nat_rev nr ON u.user_id = nr.user_id
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT nrr_id, COUNT( nad_id ) CountNatId, SUM( tmoney ) TotalNMoney
FROM nat_ads
WHERE MONTH =  'February'
GROUP BY nrr_id
)na ON nr.nrr_id = na.nrr_id
WHERE lr.month =  'February'
ORDER BY franchise
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The problem is that it is generating a row for each user, for *every* month instead of for a single month. You can see this in the below results. In the results, the rows that possess no NULL values are the rows that I want. So I just need to figure out how to eliminate the rows with NULL values.

```
userA   84  39  5200    158 NULL    NULL    NULL
userA   84  39  5200    53  NULL    NULL    NULL
userA   84  39  5200    182 NULL    NULL    NULL
userA   84  39  5200    81  5   5900    11100
userB   93  1   100     51  NULL    NULL    NULL
userB   93  1   100     200 NULL    NULL    NULL
userB   93  1   100     84  9   5742    5842
```

So, I've tried using dozens of different examples that I've found here on Stackoverflow, among other sources. I just can't get any to work when applied to my specific query. I've spent hours making random adjustments, hoping to get the result I need, but to no luck. Posting here is my absolute last resort!

Sorry for being so long-winded, I just wanted to be sure I provided all the information needed to help solve my problem. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `LEFT JOIN` on `na` to an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: SON-OF-&%*#$! Thanks so much, that did the trick. I knew it was going to be something simple like that. Much appreciated!